# Supported (and recommended) scaling methods with Azure SQL Database "Premium" (replacement for web & business)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Microsoft Azure provides an [auto-scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680945%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) feature for some of their services, including their [web sites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/web-sites/). This feature enables you to set a target CPU value, and Azure will automatically spin up or down additional "instances" of your web site in an attempt to meet your target CPU utilization. This allows you to meet demand spikes.

Most websites are backed by a datastore of some kind, whether it's MongoDB, Oracle Database, Oracle MySQL, or Azure's SQL Database. Thus, I immediately went to look at the scaling features of Azure SQL Database. As best I can tell, there is no "auto-scale" feature. Instead, you simply choose a tier and that's what you're going to get.

I've done a good bit of searching and while I've found [recommendations like this one](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/#ScalingSQLServer)<sub>1</sub>, and talk about [sharding and partitioning](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/12/23/10108670.aspx), nothing I'm finding discusses a way to "auto-scale" your Azure SQL Database in response to load. Is manual scaling the only method supported?

Comment: Footnote 1: this article mentions Web and Business editions of Azure SQL Database, which are being [replaced by new Shared, Basic, and Standard tiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn741330.aspx). However, despite the change in available tiers, the rest of the content seems applicable and in line with other discussions about scaling Azure SQL Database.

Comment: I wonder if [elastic database features](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/sql-database-elastic-scale/) would help.